# String format: leading zeroes and no trailing zeroes

Tags: c#

I'd like to format a double like this:

```
1.23 => 1.2
1.0  => 1
0.4  => 0.4
0    => 0
```

What is the corresponding string format? I'm currently using

```
StringFormat={}{0:#.#}
```

which is nice, since it leaves out a trailing zero. Unfortunatly, it turns

```
0   => ""
0.4 => .4
```

I've googled for quite some time now and find it pretty hard to find a needed string format. Would I have to adjust the culture format?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To preserve leading zeros use

```
StringFormat={}{0:0.#}
```

However, I'm confused by the translation `1.23 => 1.3`. If you meant `1.23 => 1.2`
then the format string above should work.

Comment: I am confused about this syntax. What is it? should this compile?

Comment: @DrKoch `StringFormat` is an attribute used in XAML bindings (e.g. WPF).  The prefix `{}` on the value escapes the following `{`

Answer (score 0):

Tested Ok!

```
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal("5.23");    
string sOutpu = d.ToString("0.#");
```